# TimeOut on Create Unique Index Concurrently

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create Unique Index on a table on my production box. For that:

1. Have created a table TABLE1 with COLUMN1
2. Ran following command on my production DB(which is Postgres)

   ```
    Create UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_id_unique on TABLE1(COLUMN1)
   ```

This is throwing error(after some time):

> 2014-10-07 20:46:49.056 EDT ERROR:  cancelling statement due to statement timeout
>
> 2014-10-07 20:46:49.056 EDT STATEMENT:  Create UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_id_unique on TABLE1(COLUMN1)

My Question is:

1. What could be the probable reasons for this timeout failure?
   Note: As this is production DB server, we have thousands of multiple queries/transactions running concurrently so this CREATE INDEX.... will require a significant amount of time. But still, will this query throw timeout exception?
2. Does Postgres throw statement timeout error for CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY? As this query requires multiple hours to finish for large tables.
3. What could be the probable workaround for this?

Answer (score -3):

> What could be the probable reasons for this timeout failure? Note: As
>   this is production DB server, we have thousands of multiple
>   queries/transactions running concurrently so this CREATE INDEX....
>   will require a significant amount of time. But still, will this query
>   throw timeout exception?

Well, it tells you: `cancelling statement due to statement timeout`. So, yes.

> 2. Does POSTGRES throw statement timeout error for CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY? As this query requires multiple hours to finish for large tables.

Yes, it just told you so.

> 3. What could be the probable workaround for this?

Increase the statement timeout limit for the session that's creating the index?

---

EDIT: add links to manuals

Well details on `statement_timeout` are in the manuals: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT

Likewise how to set a configuration settings are too: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html

I know nothing of this TransactionTemplate thing you are using, but google suggests it has documentation. Presumably there is some way to issue raw SQL through it if nothing else.

---

As an aside, you will find your development easier if you:

1. Carefully read provided error messages.
2. Have at least some familiarity with the manuals for the software you are using.
3. Can search for #1 against #2 via google or built-in searching.

Comment: As I am novice to DB, could you tell me how to incease the statement timeout limit?

Comment: Also, I will be calling this function from java using TransactionTemplate object. Do you have any idea on how to increase limit on that?